# How to send the object is and get the corresponding page number where that item exists in Django Rest Framework pagination?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pagination

How to use the object id and get the corresponding page number where that object belongs on all pages of the pagination in `django-rest-framework`.

What I'm trying to do here is sort of reverse pagination with `django-rest-framework`.

Is there any way to calculate the page number where a particular object belongs from all pages of the pagination and display it with the object(like in the serializer) ?

Any answer would be great!
Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the model and ordered query that you are using?

Answer (score 2):

You can perform a count of all results that would appear before the object and then divide that number by the page size to get the page that the object would appear on

```
obj = Model.objects.get(attr=value)
queryset = Model.objects.order_by('pk')
num_preceeding_results = Model.objects.filter(pk__lt=obj.pk).count()
page = num_preceeding_results // page_size + 1
```

Comment: Thank you for this nice answer!  and can you please check the following answer that I wrote and tell me whether it's okay to do it that way or not. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted `drf` pagination to give me the entire page where a particular object belongs to (with other fellow objects as well). So I overrode the `paginate_queryset` method in `rest-framewok` `pagination.PageNumberPagination` to achieve what I want and that worked. So I though to post it here as well.

In my case I have posts and answers followed by those posts. What I needed was to have a query parameter for answer id in the url which gives the entire page where that particular answer and other answers exist. Basically this is like reverse pagination.

So if I enter the following url, I'll get the result as it appears in the image.

URL: `http://localhost:8000/answer_api/?postBelong=1&answer=164`

[image]

So we don't need to enter the page number in the url. Only the answer id is enough and it gives entire page.

This is the code that I overrode.

```
def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, request, view=None):
    """
    Overriding the method to get an entire page which a particular answer is belonged,
    as asked by the user in the query parameter 'answer'
    """
    answer_id = request.query_params.get('answer', None)
    post_belong = request.query_params.get('postBelong', None)

    '''here it calculates the corresponding page number where does the answer_id belong'''
    page_num = 1
    try:
        answers = queryset.filter(postBelong=post_belong)
        for index, answer in enumerate(answers):
            if str(answer.id) == str(answer_id):
                page_num = index // ANSWERS_PER_PAGE + 1
    except Exception as exp:
        msg = str(exp)
        raise NotFound(msg)

    page_size = self.get_page_size(request)
    if not page_size:
        return None

    paginator = self.django_paginator_class(queryset, page_size)
    page_number = request.query_params.get(self.page_query_param, page_num) # changed here as the page_num
    if page_number in self.last_page_strings:
        page_number = paginator.num_pages

    try:
        self.page = paginator.page(page_number)
    except InvalidPage as exc:
        msg = self.invalid_page_message.format(
            page_number=page_number, message=str(exc)
        )
        raise NotFound(msg)

    if paginator.num_pages > 1 and self.template is not None:
        # The browsable API should display pagination controls.
        self.display_page_controls = True

    self.request = request
    return list(self.page)
```

If there is any other way to do this, please comment below because I'm also still learning these things.

Thank you!